# Remove trailing slash on domain extensions without trailing directory

Tags: php, regex

I'm importing data from a csv and I've been looking high and low for a particular regular expression to remove trailing slashes from domain names without a directory after it. See the following example:

```
example.com/ (remove trailing slash)
example.co.uk/ (remove trailing slash)
example.com/gb/ (do not remove trailing slash)
```

Can anyone help me out with this or at least point me in the right direction?

Edit: This is my progress so far, I've only matched the extension at the moment but it's picking up those domains with trailing directories.

```
[a-z0-9\-]+[a-z0-9]\/[a-z]
```

Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried already? Show *input*, *actual output*, *expected output*

Comment: I have edited my answer to include my current progress with the regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how it would compare to a regular expression performance-wise, but you can do it without one.

A simple example:

```
$string = rtrim ($string, '/');
$string .= (strpos($string, '/') === false) ? '' : '/';
```

In the second line I'm only adding a `/` at the end if the string already contains one (to separate domain from folder).

A more solid approach would probably be to only `rtrim` if the first `/` found, is the last character of the string.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much; and thank you to everyone else with their suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

not sure,

but you can try this,

if it is a `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` only then remove slash otherwise keep it

because $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] will return URL without any directory

try this

```
/^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}(:[a-z0-9]*)?\/?([a-z0-9\-\._\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$/i
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work as I'm importing data from a csv file and need to clean the urls before adding them to a database. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: ok try this, i have edited the answer /^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}(:[a-z0-9]*)?\/?([a-z0-9\-\._\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$/i

Answer (score 0):

you could test for a match on /[a-z]/, then remove the last charater if it's not found.

this is javascript, but it'd be similar in php.

```
/\/[a-z]+\//

var txt = 'example.com/gb/';
var match = txt.match(/\/[a-z]+\//);
if (!match) {
    alert(txt.substring(txt,txt.length-1));
}
else {
    alert(txt);   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjKTS/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works：

```
<?
$result = preg_replace('/^([^\/]+)(\/)$/','$1',$your_data);
?>
```

I have tested like this:

```
$reg = '/^([^\/]+)(\/)$/';

echo preg_replace($reg,'$1',$str1);//example.com
echo preg_replace($reg,'$1',$str2);//example.co.uk
echo preg_replace($reg,'$1',$str3);//example.com/gb/
?>
```